# WGen20000 generator hook-up to the whole house using both 50 A outlets at the same time

Tags: generator

I am looking for a way to hook up a [WGen20000](https://westinghouseoutdoorpower.com/collections/generators/products/wgen20000-generator) generator to my house to use the full power possibility of that generator.

Is there any way to hook up mentioned generator utilizing both 50 A outlets to my electrical service panel at the same time?

The simplest way I can see is just install two 50 A inlet boxes and wire them to two separate 50 A breakers which are connected to the same service panel - is this going to work?

Another way could be to set up two transfer switches for separate usage - one switch for the first floor and the other for the second.

Could you please advise the most correct way to do it if possible?

Comment: if I have two inlets connected to two breakers and hooked up to a single panel, will   the load be shared evenly?

Comment: Can you post photos of your existing service panel please?

Answer (score 4):

### Generator safety is *extremely important*

Because you can kill people a mile away - the linemen who are struggling to restore grid power to your home!

To start with, your panel must be *interlocked* so it is physically impossible (without wrecking stuff) to have the utility main breaker, and the generator breaker on at the same time.  That's not compatible with the idea of using two breakers on the main panel, so obviously you are willing to throw the interlock safety feature out the window so you can get power for luxuries, since nobody has 50A of emergency loads.

We have a Be Nice Policy here, so I must presume this is only a "lack of sufficient information" issue, and you'll be all too happy to get on-board with safety once you have the 411.  *Well, here we go.*

[image]

### Generator interlock required

And the most cost-efficient way to do this is a "Generator Interlock", which is a sliding plate attached to the panel which prevents both the main breaker and generator breaker from being on at the same time.  A 100A generator interlock is not a problem; they go up to 125A.

They are not costly, and are typically in the $30 to $70 range for newer panels, and a bit more for older panels.  Depending on the arrangement of your panel, this may not be possible *that way*, in which case some panel work will be required. We can guide you, given photos of your panel(s).

Those $500 6-8-10 circuit "transfer switches" do provide the necessary safety interlock. However they are problematic in the modern age and would never be approved by UL if they were submitted today.  With MWBC circuits they are themselves a hazard, and they don't work with GFCI or AFCI breakers (and can damage the breakers).

If you want a separate box, or if you can't use a generator interlock for some reason, use a **critical-loads subpanel**. This is simply a normal subpanel with a generator interlock between two main breakers.  For instance a 30-space Siemens *main-lug* panel with the $30 Siemens ECSBPK01 interlock.  One main breaker is fed from a regular breaker in the main panel. The other main breaker comes from the generator.  Any circuits you might want to power, MOVE them to this critical loads panel. **There is no limit to the number of circuits moved over** other than the number of panel spaces you choose to buy.  Spaces are cheap up to 40-space, so obviously we recommend a 40-space critical loads sub if you can site it.  Note you lose 4 spaces for the interlock.

This also frees up a ton of spaces in your main panel, since the circuits are *moved* here. If you had a "panel full" problem there, you don't anymore :)

### How do you hook up 100A of generator?

TLDR: you either **Hardwire** it, or use a special type of connector rated for the amperage, which I get as 90A here.

Honestly just about all the experts here would hard-wire it.  It's easy and cheap, and the lugs you need are accessible on this machine.

Paralleling two sockets into one panel is Right Out.  It can't be properly interlocked, and it has a 50% chance of making a Very Loud Boom and burning your entire setup to a crisp.  Total disaster, don't even think about it.

Now, some people propose having *two* critical loads subpanels with *two* interlocks, each fed by an inlet.   That would work fine for two separate generators.  Does not work for splitting from a single generator, because it creates a nasty Neutral Loop between the generators.    Now, there is a trick you can do to break that "neutral loop" - you can get a common industrial 240/480V--120/240V isolation transformer, often seen on Craigslist or Facebook Marketplace at sane cost (cheaper than a 6/8/10 circuit transfer switch, even)... and stick that transformer in between the inlet and panel on one of the panels. This isolates neutral and breaks the neutral loop. But this only works with 2 inlets feeding 2 panels.

This question comes up a lot on DIY, and that's what we've come up with.

Well, the last way involves DC coupling - run the whole house off an inverter off a battery, and then you can have any number of battery chargers working in parallel to feed that DC bus.  But that's not practical at the price range you're trying to hit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please advise where I can hardwire generator, or any electrician can do it?

Comment: @ArtemTceunov If you read the instructions for un-bonding neutral, the terminals are right there.  An electrician will have an easy time of it.  There is no need for a breaker since the generator is physically unable to make more than 115A. Just use 115A wire (#2 copper) and a 90-125A breaker in your panel.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing to the terminal wiring in the manual, I overlooked this moment. Could you please point where is located that terminal on the wiring diagram of the whole generator. Is it located before or after CT unit?

Answer (score 1):

There is no location informaton in your post so we don't know what local regulations apply but in any country what you are proposing is dangerous and therefore unlikely to be permitted.

The biggest problem is that if one cable is unplugged and the generator is running then the pins of the other inlet are live and prevent a shock hazard.

The two transfer switches scheme sounds safer but again local regulations would have to be satisfied.

Comment: thank you for your reply. the house located in Texas. I am understanding, if one of the cables unplugged other one will be overloaded and breaker should shut off service line.

Comment: No, you can't rely on that. If the load is reduced due to stuff getting switched off then the circuit breaker will not trip. As a matter of principle we don't design / allow circuits with exposed live terminals.

Answer (score 0):

It *can* be done, but that assumes you have two separate panels that can be interlocked, one to each inlet. You can't have two inlets to one panel with any of the usual interlock devices, and I don't hink anyone makes an unusual interlock device that would allow that. Or, if the generator is dedicated to the job, skip the receptacles & plugs and hardwire it to a 100A inlet breaker.

*i.e.* I could do this easily, as I have 400A service that goes to two 200A panels, *each of which* has an interlock and inlet (allowing me to power any circuit by where I plug in the generator and which breakers I turn on.)

That may require adding a subpanel, and it definitely requires adding a manual interlock on each panel with an inlet at the bare minimum. Transfer switches are only needed in the case of automatic operation - manual interlocks are plenty (and far less expensive) if setup and operation of the generator is a manual process.